# Diagonal div with image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve a similar result to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmRye.png)

Preferably the black and blue parts are separate divs, because what I'm trying to achieve will otherwise be very hard/impossible. The HTML code would look something like

```
<div class="diagonal">
    <div class="diagonal-black"></div>
    <div class="diagonal-blue"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Using borders on a pseudo-element:**

```css
.diagonal {width:700px; height:200px;}
.diagonal-black {float:left; background:black; width:50%; height:200px;}
.diagonal-blue {float:right; background:blue; width:50%; height:200px; position:relative;}
.diagonal-blue:after {position:absolute; content:""; width:0; top:0; left:-50px; height:0; border-bottom:200px solid transparent; border-right:50px solid blue;}
```

```html
<div class="diagonal">
    <div class="diagonal-black"><img src="https://placekitten.com/350/200" alt="" /></div>
    <div class="diagonal-blue"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is almost what I need. Say I want to replace the black with an image, how would I do that?

Comment: then what would you want it to look like?  would the blue diagonal bit lay on top of the image?

Comment: Yes, that would be perfect.

Comment: modified the code to include an image in place of the black div.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most common way is to use clip-path. Another way is using borders. There are tutorials on both. Here is an example of how to make your example work

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/1uaxo0x4/)

```
.diagonal {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background: blue;
}
.diagonal-black {
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(74% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
clip-path: polygon(74% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

And here is a site used to easily generate your preferred shape and angle [Clippy](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for, the left part should be resizable without influencing the right part

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
<div class='diagonal'></div>

<style>
.diagonal {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.diagonal::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200%;
  background-color: blue;
  -webkit-transform: skewX(45deg) translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: skewX(45deg) translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: skewX(45deg) translateX(-50%);
  -o-transform: skewX(45deg) translateX(-50%);
  transform: skewX(45deg) translateX(-50%);
}
</style>
```

Basically this way all you have to do is adjust the `transform`, `width`, and/or `height` to get it in the exact position you want.

[jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/bunikiyafe/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: The thing is that I need to be able to modify the content of the 2 divs, which I can't with this example. Thanks though.